# What is it that raises my footer in my Pages 7.0.1. document

Tags: pages, text-input

In my Pages document, at the bottom of p. 9 I have a star, followed by a blank line, followed by some text :

[image]

To save space, I delete that blank line between the star and the text (by putting the cursor inside it and hitting "Delete"). But the result is that the footer is raised, and all in all no space is saved :

[image]
This surprising behavior happens for some paragraphs and not for others. What is going on here ? How may I fix this ?